# Oracle 10 - query short circuit evaluation

Tags: oracle, plsql

Does Oracle 10 support a short circuit evaluation query? if yes, there are some special key for use it?

Comment: What do you mean by short circuit query? Could you provide an example?

Comment: A short circuit query means that if in the where clause I have something like "WHERE A = B OR B = C", if the first clause is true it doesn't check the second

Comment: a simple comparison between two values is almost nothing compared to cost of reading the blocks from disk. Or reading the information from block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably talking about short circuit evaluation.

A DBMS has [cost-based optimizer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58246/optimiz.htm). There is no guarantee wich condition will get evaluated first and there's no special key to activate this.

*Note that PL/SQL **does** use short circuit evaluation*

Answer (score 3):

The only short circuit I have seen Oracle do, relates to NVL vs COALESCE.

```
SELECT NVL(1,1/0) FROM DUAL

SELECT COALESCE(1,1/0) FROM DUAL
```

NVL evaluates both sides and throws an error, the coalesce doesn't.

It also looks like `decode` is doing the same thing:

```
SELECT decode(1,1,9,2,1/0) FROM DUAL
```

It isn't evaluating the second part so avoids throwing an error.

On the SQL Server optimizer, I know that the query engine can rewrite these kind of statements and cause problems with short circuit examples like this so as a general rule - you should never rely on a short circuit within your logic - I do not know if the same applies to Oracle - I suspect it will.